# can't convert nil into String - regex issue? "\n\n"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm following this tutorial - http://communityguides.heroku.com/articles/9 -app/controllers/admin_controller.rb

Stuck on a "can't convert nil into String" error with the following block of code.

```
# freeze state 
@article.freezebody = @article.title + "\n\n" + @article.teaser + "\n\n" + @article.body + "\n\n" + @article.version + "\n\n" + @article.changelog 
@article.accepted = Time.now
```

Is this a regex issue? I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One ore more of your attributes is `nil`, and this:

```
nil + ''
```

will give you the exception you're seeing.

To concatenate those attributes, minus any that might be nil (shortened for readibility):

```
[@article.title, @article.teaster].compact.join("\n\n")
```

`compact` removes all `nil` objects from the array.